# Regexp in PathVariable does not work correctly Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, path-variables

There is a controller.

I make a request `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/download/avatar/1/GtAHWk3EVjBcltY.JPG` - I get `404`. It does not reach the method. Why? What is wrong in the regular season?

I use Spring Boot 2. But the thing is that there is a project, without a boot and there is the same mapping - everything is ok.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/download")
public class DownloadRestController {

    private final DownloadService downloadService;

    @Autowired
    public DownloadRestController(DownloadService downloadService) {
        this.downloadService = downloadService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/avatar/{path:.*}")
    public void download(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable String path) {
        this.downloadService.download(request, "/avatar/"+path);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you do something like that? Can't you just have a regular string?

Comment: @Pijotrek no. Data after `/avatar/` is dynamic.

Comment: Yeah, so? `/avatar/{path}` and `@PathVariable("path") String path` should work. No need for `.*` stuff. Try it please.

Comment: @Pijotrek not working - 404.

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/download/avatar/1/GtAHWk3EVjBcltY.JPG` - look, there are 2 path variables `/1` and `/GtAHWk3EVjBcltY.JPG` hence your error

Comment: Let me put it in an answer because it's cumbersome to paste code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/download/avatar/1/GtAHWk3EVjBcltY.JPG
```

and your method accepts `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/download/avatar/{path}`.

So you are passing two `@PathVariable`s - this is why you are getting `HTTP-404`.
You have to decide if you want

```
@PathVariable("id") long id, @PathVariable("path") String path
```

with 2 Path Variables
or

```
@PathVariable("path") String path
```

with a single one.

Moreover, to add to the above, putting some regexp-like stuff is not neccessary for you.

```
@PathVariable("path") String path
```

in your arguments should work well.

Comment: I not need parse every parameter. I want make universal request for all files. In Other project, without Spring Boot, this work perfectly. But here is - 404. But same code.

Comment: It is going to be 404 forever when you call with two path variables and accept only one.

Comment: fine. But why this `/avatar/{path:.*}` work in other project with spring 5?

Comment: I have no idea. But I am pretty sure that if you apply my changes it's going to work for you. Just add that `@PathVariable("id") long id` and `/avatar/{id}/{path}`

Comment: @Tsyklop did you try it? did it help?

Comment: yes, i tried it. but path file need write like this: `{path:.+}`. Simple variant `{path}` does not work.

Comment: This is very strange since the filename is a regular string. But I'm glad you grasped it